# event.preventDefault() is not stopping code from running

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html page and the following javascript :

The page is supposed to display a picture at a random location and to refresh it every 4 seconds (screensaver page). If no mouse action or tablet touch is detected (hence the event listeners added in the setup page), the action continues forever. It has worked perfectly fine until I've modified the `goActive` function to add the `window.open("index.html")` line. Now the problem is that screensaver is never displayed and it immediately follows the next instruction to open the index.html page. I thought that adding the line `event.preventDefault` would solve my problem.

Any idea what I am doing wrong at this stage?

```js
function init() {
 var xmin = 0;
 var xmax = 890;
 var ymin = 0;
 var ymax = 430;

 var xCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*xmax)+xmin);
 var yCoord = Math.floor((Math.random()*ymax)+ymin);

 var xCoordStr = xCoord.toString() + "px";
 var yCoordStr = yCoord.toString() + "px";

 document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.left = xCoordStr;
 document.getElementById("randomPlacement").style.top = yCoordStr;

 document.getElementById("date").innerhtml=getDate('date');
 document.getElementById("time").innerhtml=getTime('time');
}
function setup() {
 this.addEventListener("mousemove", exitScreenSaver, false);
 this.addEventListener("mousedown", exitScreenSaver, false);
 this.addEventListener("keypress", exitScreenSaver, false);
 this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", exitScreenSaver, false);
 this.addEventListener("mousewheel", exitScreenSaver, false);
 this.addEventListener("touchmove", exitScreenSaver, false);
 this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", exitScreenSaver, false);
}

function exitScreenSaver(e) {
 goActive();
}

function goActive() {
// do something
 console.log(".. active ..");
 event.preventDefault();
 window.open("index.html","_self");
}
```

```css
 /* Page entière (utilisé pour avoir une couverture globale en couleur) */
body {
    background-color:black;  /*screensaver mode*/
}

/* Affichage de date (en haut) */
#date{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 20px;
    color:white;        /* screensaver mode*/
}

/* Affichage d'heure (en haut) */
#time{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 300px;
    color:white;        /* screensaver mode*/
}
/* Affichage de la température */
#tag_temperature{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 600px;
    color:black;        /* night mode*/
    color:blue;         /* day mode*/
    color:white;        /* screensaver mode*/
}

p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- 
 Page d'économiseur d'écran, créée le 30.07.2016 
 modifiée le 02.09.2016 
 modifiée le 22.10.2016 (no cache) 
 modifiée le 23.10.2016 (inclusion de la date et de l'heure)
-->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Domoos | Screen saver screen</title>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_saver.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/screensaver.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init(); setup();">
 <div style="position:absolute" id="randomPlacement">
  <p><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/pictures/texte_sortie_veille.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;"></a></p>
 </div>
 <div id="date"></div>
 <div id="time"></div>
 <div id="tag_temperature">
  <p>?&deg;C</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have not defined the getDate function

Comment: the getDate and getTime functions are embedded in another javascript that I forgot to enclose in the snippet :/

Comment: `event` is not defined.

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol. Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Thanks

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. You are using this variable called `event` but you haven't defined it anywhere.

Comment: Inside `goActive()` -- `event.preventDefault()` -- Niet is saying `event` is `undefined` there. Try passing it from `exitScreenSaver` to `goActive`, or better yet, just remove `goActive` and put that code inside `exitScreenSaver` (either renaming `e` to `event` or changing `event` to `e`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the e parameter to the goActive function

```
function exitScreenSaver(e) {
    goActive(e);
}

function goActive(event) {
    // do something
    console.log(".. active ..");
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open("index.html","_self");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mate, I have been replicating your code, played with it for a while. Script appears to run OK. You have some little things, though:

-You are declaring functions after they've been called.

-Passing the object 'e' and not using it.

-Using the .html to call `init()` & `setup()`. Instead of `window.addEventListener('load', init, false);`

The main problem is that you probably deleted statements in `goActive()`. That function runs, but just types `...active...` in console and opens up another page, there is no extra functionality, cause it is not written!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your valuable inputs. I really appreciate. Any hint to improve the responsiveness, especially on a tablet?

Comment: That's ok. I tend to use percentage values and @media queries to avoid things like '500px' ,'800px' as that works different for different resolutions.